# When do we need to destroy Ember.Object

Tags: ember.js

Does ember clear up ember object if we have coded stuff like this:

```
App.someController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
    someList: [Em.Object.create({...}), Em.Object.create({...})]
});
```

or do we have to manually clean them up? Also if we had to clean them up manually, would we have to call destroy on them explicitly or maybe something like this would do the trick:

```
willDestroy: function(){
     this.get('someList').clear();//object reference is removed so the GC will do the rest??
}
```

Your response will be much appreciated. And even if you have general recommendation on what would help in better GC(specially ie8 but not restricted to) that would be great too. Thanks.

Comment: I see you're still having issues, can you expand on the hardware (cpu, ram) and the type of pages you're building, the type of problems you're experiencing, and even maybe an example?  IE8 is terrible when it comes to javascript in general, especially since it still had the max statements per loop limitation.

Comment: Thanks @kingpin2k for offering to help, much appreciated. Our app is fairly complex and i am not sure if i can come up with a jsbin that can be close replication of the app, but may be i can spin up a simple app with base logics which can help isolate/reproduce the memory hog issue by tomorrow. Thanks.